# Excel VBA AutoFilter adds empty rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have modified my Excel Macro, which before went row by row and it now filters the results and copies in bulk. Much more efficient.

The problem I encouter now, the Auto Filter adds Millions of empty rows to the Worksheet and I can't identify why it does so.

CountryCodes is a dictionary which contains the values for the filter.
Criteria is looking for rows that contain the entry from the dictionary.

This is the code:

```
    For Each vall In CountryCodes
    thisWB.Activate
    thisWB.Sheets("Overall Numbers").Activate

    lookfor = CountryCodes.Item(vall)
    rep = Replace(thisWBName, "EMEA", lookfor)

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z1")

    FilterField = WorksheetFunction.Match("Host", rng.Rows(1), 0)

    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then rng.AutoFilter

    rng.AutoFilter Field:=FilterField, Criteria1:="=*" & lookfor & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues

    Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overall Numbers").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    rng2.Copy Workbooks(rep).Worksheets("Overall Numbers").Range("A1")

    Workbooks(rep).Save

    thisWB.Activate
    thisWB.Sheets("Overall Numbers").Activate

    Cells.AutoFilter
Next
```

Comment: I have also tried adding the filter using Excel Filters and I get the same result - Empty rows being added at the end. This drives me nuts!

Comment: +1 for converting the loop to AutoFilter. You should open your initial files and delete all empty rows and you'll see a significant decrease in file size, and faster performance when updating the data. Select first empty row (not just a single cell) and press Shift+Ctrl+Down Arrow, then **don't press the Delete key**, instead right-click one of the selected rows and select Delete from the pop-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested:

```
Dim ur As Range
Set ur = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overall Numbers").UsedRange

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
filterField = Application.Match("Host", ur.Rows(1), 0)
If Not IsError(filterField) Then

    For Each vall In countryCodes
       rep = Replace(thisWBName, "EMEA", vall)

       ur.AutoFilter Field:=filterField, Criteria1:="=*" & vall & "*"

       'copy visible rows with data only
       ur.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

       'paste visible rows with data only
       Workbooks(rep).Worksheets("Overall Numbers").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
       Workbooks(rep).Save

       ur.AutoFilter
    Next
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Had to make some minor changes but it works now! :D - Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

I've reorganized your code and removed the `.Activate` reliance and isolated the filtered data with the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx).

```
With thisWB
    With .Worksheets("Overall Numbers")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False

        lookfor = CountryCodes.Item(vall)
        rep = Replace(thisWBName, "EMEA", lookfor)

        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            FilterField = WorksheetFunction.Match("Host", .Rows(1), 0)
            For Each vall In CountryCodes
                .AutoFilter Field:=FilterField, Criteria1:="=*" & lookfor & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0))) Then
                    .Copy Workbooks(rep).Worksheets("Overall Numbers").Range("A1")
                    Workbooks(rep).Save
                End If
                .AutoFilter Field:=FilterField
            Next vall
        End With
    End With
    .AutoFilter
End With
```

Unless `rep` is somehow incremented, this appears to paste to the same workbook/worksheet/range for every iteration.

Comment: Works too! - Thanks! :D